# I'm getting 'page not found' when trying to access my custom module

Tags: routes

I am working from a pre-existing Drupal 7 install.  I downloaded the source files and downloaded a dump of the DB. When I first installed Drupal worked fine.  I built a custom module, it was working just the way it needed to, a link to the page appeared in the navigation, and I was able to navigate directly to the page by typing in the url.  Yesterday, I had to download a new dump of the DB, drop the tables from the DB I had in place and import the new download.  After doing that, my module still shows in the available modules to enable, but it isn't in the navigation and when I try to type the pages url, it say's "The requested page "/TLSConnect3App/floor_map_page" could not be found." I've tried disabling/enabling it  clearing caches, I've even tried replacing my hook_menu with an example, but nothing seems to work.

Here is my hook_menu :

```
function floor_map_menu() {
    $items = array();

    $items['floor_map_page'] = array(
        'title'     => t('Floor Map'),
        'page callback' => 'floor_map_page',
        'access callback'   => TRUE,
        'type'          => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    );

    $items['floor_map_page/floor_map'] = array(
        'title'             => t('Floor Map'),
        'page callback' => 'floor_map_page',
        'access callback'   => TRUE,
        'type'          => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
    );
    $items['floor_map_page/setup_floor_map'] = array(
        'title'             => t('Floor Map Setup'),
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'access callback'   => TRUE,
        'page arguments'    => array('new_floor_map_form'),
        'type'          => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    );
    $items['floor_map_page/select_floor_map'] = array(
        'title'             => t('Floor Map Select'),
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments'    => array('select_floor_map_form'),
        'access callback'   => TRUE,
        'type'          => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    );
    return $items;
}
```

And here is an example I tried replacing it with:

```
function quick_menu() {

  $items = array();
  $items['quick/hello'] = array( // change to the url you want
    'title' => 'Quick Hello',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page callback' => 'quick_hello',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );

  return $items;
}

function quick_hello() {

  $content='Hello. Thank you for surfing over to ' . $_GET['q'];
  return $content;
}
```

Either way, I get the same message, "Page not found"....
I'm assuming the page callbacks are in a database table and I wiped that out with the import, but reinstalling the module/clearing caches should fix this, right?

I did find a script here: https://drupal.org/node/559364
but it is for Drupal 6..

Have also tried using menu_rebuild() and clearing all caches several times now.

So, I just went through and changed everything in my module that say's floor_map to floormap and it's working now..not the best way to fix the issue, but I can actually see my pages now, so I'll take it.

Comment: A reinstall of the module will not necessarily fix the path issues.  Have you done a `menu_rebuild` (either the function directly or via the devel module)?

Comment: Clear the cache and try again.

Comment: @WayneWeibel No, I havn't tried that, I will give it a shot.

Comment: @Rupesh I have cleared the cache...have done so several times.

Comment: @WayneWeibel I am having trouble getting to menu_rebuild.  The instructions I've found have me inserting <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

menu_rebuild(); into a php file in the root Drupal directory and then navigating to that, trouble is, I get the same "Page not found" error when I try to get to the file in the root directory.  Not sure how to access it using the devel module...can't find any help for that

Comment: Since you have the devel module (installed I assume), enable the devel block, this gives you a set of basic commands that can be done via a link, rebuild menus is one.  

Also, just to be sure, you did enable your module again yes?

Comment: Yes it is enabled

Comment: Thank you for the Devel instructions, rebuilding menu's didn't help

Comment: Your code is perfect so the only possible problem I can think of is that your hooks are named incorrectly - what's the name of your module? As in, what's the .info file called? If it's `floor_map.info` then the first example will work; if it's `quick.info`, the second example will work. If it's neither, that's likely to be the problem

Comment: when I was using floor_map the file names were floor_map.info,floor_map.module, and with floormap it was floormap.info, floormap.module.  I did not change the name for the quick example I tried.